# How to access variables from one scene to another scene in Storyboard app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an app that has 2 scenes. In one scene I have some UITextFields to enter the data and a set button to assign that data to variables. As soon as they click the set button the second scene appears. Now, I want to access the variables from first scene to this one. I mean from the first view controller to second view controller (segue).

Comment: See [`prepareForSegue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) which is designed for passing information from one scene to another. If you google examples, you'll get tons of hits. Or if you search StackOverflow for `prepareForSegue`. This is well trod territory and you should search before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are using two scenes. Lets call them ViewController1 and ViewController2. If you are sending the data from one to two then add ViewController2.h in your Viewcontroller1.m. In ViewController1.m, lets say if you are getting the textfield value in a string, `NSString *str;` (make sure to name the segue. lets say its name is "hello"). In ViewContoller2 initialize another variable called `NSString *str1;`. You can pass the variable to ViewController2 by the following method,

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"hello"])
{
    NSString *str;
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc2.str1 = str;
}
    }
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any information you need from the first to the second by overriding prepareForSegue on the first. The destination controller can be referenced through segue.destinationViewController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```